# State.go for AngularJs UI Routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I setup a small example based on the article posted on setting up UI routing.

I modified the example to test explicitly navigating from a child nested state to sibling state using `$state.go()`. any ideas what I am doing wrong?

I keep getting the error below:
[Error resolving State. Could not resolve .paragraph from state home.list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MwYT.jpg)

```js
        $stateProvider
            
            // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
            })
            
            // nested list with custom controller
            .state('home.list', {
                url: '/list',
                templateUrl: 'partial-home-list.html',
                controller: function($scope,$state) {
                    $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
                     $scope.navigateToNextState = function () {
                            $state.go('.paragraph');
                        };
                }
            })
            
            // nested list with just some random string data
            .state('home.paragraph', {
                url: '/paragraph',
                template: 'I could sure use a drink right now.'
            })
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Nae6xz9qcBp3IRYi0wcD?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller should be adjusted like this:

```
controller: function($scope, $state) {
     $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
     $scope.navigateToNextState = function () {
         $state.go('^.paragraph');
     };
}
```

We need a `$state` as one of function params. And we are in a child, so we have to use `'^.paragraph'` *(instead of `'.paragraph'`)* to ask for **another child of our parent**

Checked [working fixed version here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UlzG1Y7n41pgWd0MG3xm?p=preview)